# How to achieve a perfect align between two overlapping ellipses?

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

Some time ago I created an experimental drawing program to draw with ellipses. Unlike most programs, the ellipse starts where the mouse is clicked (the leading edge, the tip of the ellipse, not its focus) and ends where the click is released, in the desired direction relative to the first point and the mouse cursor. The width is modified with the mouse wheel. You can use the last point (where the mouse button was released) to connect another ellipse.

My idea is to do the same thing, but connect the ellipses with a smooth curvature between them at their outer edges. I could see that no matter how different the ellipses are, there is always a point where the curve is almost perfect, for this to happen, the ellipses have to overlap.

The problem and my question, try to determine which is the position to place the second ellipse, according to its parameters and the parameters of the first one already drawn. As it is difficult for me to explain, I leave an image that I made with Geogebra.

More than the mathematics involved, I would like to understand the idea and the relationship between the curvatures of the ellipses to obtain the desired result or an approximate way to achieve it. I think it would be great to draw more organic base shapes with ellipses filled with an opaque color.

Thank you for reading!

Draw with ellipses example:

[image: img]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming issues

Comment: What you are asking is called G2 continuity.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time here, the final result is to be programmed but I'm interested in the idea of how to do it, in pseudocode or whatever. Thanks Yves, I'll look up what you mention.

Comment: @YvesDaoust its `G?` the same as `C?` continuity? or `C` is at endpoints and `G` at overlaps ? I am just currious ... also `?` degree is counting from zero or from one in English terminology? IIRC someone here on SO commented me once that C counts form one in English (I am used to count from zero convention)

Comment: @Spektre C is more strict parametric continuity (G is geometric one) - so for C1 tangent direction and tangent length should coincide, while G1 ought to provide only  tangent direction. So, for example, C1 gives smooth moving along curves, but for G1 speed might change in joint point. G2 gives equal curvature radius, while C2 adds acceleration continuity.

Comment: @Spektre: C continuity only makes sense for curves that are parameterized. This is irrelevant in the frame of this post. [This is not contradictory with my answer, that uses a parametric representation - but only on one side.]

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

An ellipse of parametric equations `x=a cos t`, `y=b sin t` has a tangent vector in the direction `(-a sin t, b cos t)`, and curvature `ab/(a² sin²t+b² cos²t)^3/2`. The curvature is congruency-invariant.

Choosing a `t`, and a connection point on the other ellipse (with known direction and curvature), the curvature imposes the ratio `a/b` and in turn the direction of the tangent. Now you have one degree of freedom left (scaling) to set `a` and `b`, and you translate and rotate to achieve `G1` continuity.

Comment: Thanks @Yves Daoust, I am carefully studying your answer. If I have more questions or if I get results, I'll share them here...

Comment: @EstebanGomez: sorry, the curvature formula was wrong. This changes the method a little. You can choose the curvature and the ratio a/b independently.